# <ScrollControls> from the drei library is causing an "issue" with <Html>, but only if enableZoom={false} is set for <OrbitControls>

Tags: html, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

When I add <ScrollControls>, even if I'm not controlling the camera, the <Html> tag that should be in a specific position in the 3D scene gets displaced incorrectly when scrolling. It should actually move based on the camera. Does anyone know what's happening and how to prevent this?

This is the code where you can see what the problem is: https://codesandbox.io/s/da-ttgdx7

I expect the <Html> tag not to move based on <ScrollControls>, but to move relative to the camera.

Here is react code:

```
import { Html, ScrollControls, OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <ScrollControls>
        <Html
          position={[-8.5, 12.9, 1.43]}
          distanceFactor={4}
          style={{
            height: 784,
            width: 1698,
            position: "fixed",
            backgroundColor: "#03b6fc",
            borderRadius: "60px"
          }}
          transform
        ></Html>
        <mesh rotation-x={Math.PI * 1.5} position={[0, -2, 0]}>
          <planeGeometry args={[100, 100, 1, 1]} />
          <meshBasicMaterial color={"#00ff00"} />
        </mesh>
      </ScrollControls>
    </>
  );
}
```

and this is dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "9.83.9",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.14.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "three": "0.156.1"
  },
```

Comment: This likely because OrbitControlls is camera, and scroll controls offsets scene

Comment: Even if OrbitControls is turned off, the same thing happens. When scrolling, the HTML moves. It only works correctly when OrbitControls is enabled with enableZoom={true}.